# how to set bold and italic property in component label using angular4

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I am having a inside that component there is a template and selector 
here is my component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'labelnumeric',
    template: '<label>hello</label>'
})

export class LabelNumeric
{

}
```

I want to add a property to the label bold and italic dynamically so how can i do this?

Comment: Do you mean to set the label to `bold` and `italic` dynamically? for static you can just do `<label><b><i>hello</i></b></label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this. You have to define `.class-bold` in css. Either in the decorator or externally.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'labelnumeric',
    template: '<label #mylabel>hello</label>'
})

export class LabelNumeric implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('mylabel') label;

  @Input() isBold: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.isBold){
      this.label.nativeElement.classList.add('class-bold');
    }
  }
}
```

And use it like this: `<labelnumeric [isBold]="true"></labelnumeric>`

If that works you can define an @Input for italic accordingly.

Comment: and suppose i want to change the label text through html control so how can i do this?

Comment: I would use `@Input() labelText = 'default text';` in the class and `{{labelText}}` in the template. So you can pass in a string `<labelnumeric labelText="hello"></labelnumeric>`.

Comment: can you make it in a fiddle pls

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ngClass` for this.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'labelnumeric',
    template: ' <label [ngClass]="{'font-italic': someCondition, 'font-bold' : someOtherCondition}">hello</label>'
})

export class LabelNumeric
{

}
```

assign these two classes on some conditions, then using css you can set font-style and font-weight.

```
.font-italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.font-bold {
  font-weight: bold
  }
```